# After OpenSuse upgrade from 12.1 to 12.2 there is no sound

Tags: opensuse

After OpenSuse 12.1 64bit upgrade to OpenSuse 12.2 their is no sound however test sound is played in KDE Phonon application.
Under the root account sound is working normally.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here: http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/multimedia/479556-test-audio-works-but-no-sound-any-application-3.html

It turns out that it is necessary to add audio / pulse / pulse access groups to
the user under which sound is not working.